# Preventing copies of dictionary when using pool.map()

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a function `f(x)` I want to evaluate over list of values `xrange` in parallel. The function does something like this:

```
def f(x, wrange, dict1, dict2):

    out_list = []

    v1 = dict1[x]

    for w in wrange:
        v2 = dict2[x-w]
        out_list += [np.dot(v1, v2)]

    return out_list
```

it takes values a matrix from a dictionary `dict1`, a vector from dictionary `dict2`, then multiplies them together. Now my normal approach for doing this in parallel would be something like this:

```
import functools
import multiprocessing

par_func = functools.partial(f, wrange=wrange, dict1=dict1, dict2=dict2)

p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
ssdat = p.map(par_func, wrange)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Now when `dict1` and `dict2` are big dictionaries, this causes the code to fail with the error

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

and I think this is because `pool` is making copies of the `dict1` and `dict2` for every evaluation of my function. Is there an efficient way, instead, to set these dictionaries as shared memory objects? Is `map` the best function to do this?

Comment: You may try with `threading` instead. If your `np.dot()` is computationally expensive you may not notice the difference between mutiprocessing and multithreading as NumPy should release the GIL while calculating the matrix product.

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of [Python multiprocessing - Why is using functools.partial slower than default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35062087/364696), but the focus is different (this asks how, the other question asks why); I'll leave it up to others to make that decision.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, this gave some good background to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a `fork`-based system (read: Not Windows), one solution to this problem is to put the `dict`s in question in globals, write a function that doesn't take them as arguments, but simply access them from its own globals, and use that. [`functools.partial` is, unfortunately, unsuited to this use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35062087/364696), but your use case makes it easy to replace with globals and a `def`-ed function:

```
import multiprocessing

# Assumes wrange/dict1/dict2 defined or imported somewhere at global scope,
# prior to creating the Pool
def par_func(x):
    return f(x, wrange, dict1, dict2)

# Using with statement implicitly terminates the pool, saving close/join calls
# and guaranteeing an exception while mapping doesn't leave the pool alive indefinitely
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
    ssdat = p.map(par_func, wrange)
```

Changes to `dict1`/`dict2` won't be reflected between processes after the `Pool` is created, but you seem to be using it in a read-only fashion anyway, so that's not a problem.

If you're on Windows, or need to mutate the `dict`s, you can always [make a `multiprocessing.Manager` and make `dict` proxies with the `dict` method of the manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict) (these are shared `dict`s, updated on key assignment), but it's uglier and slower, so I'd discourage it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share memory between processes using multiprocessing, you'll need to explicitly share the objects with [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array).  That's not ideal since you're wanting to access elements from dicts and finding the correct data might be time consuming.  There are likely ways around this if it does become a problem for you.

As @Peque mentioned, the other option is to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).  With threading, memory is automatically shared across all processes but you can run into performance issues due to the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (GIL).  The GIL is Python's way to keep you thread-safe and avoid race conditions.